# having problem with proguard trying to obfuscate code that uses Spring

Tags: java, spring, obfuscation, proguard

My project uses spring for IoC. After obfuscation the application context fails to find the bean since it's class name has been changed. I tried to use -adaptresourcefilecontents
option to get context.xml file be updated according to the class name, but it didn't work: the file wasn't changed.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add [file filter](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#filefilters), I don't know if proguard looks at xml file as well.

Also, the documentation mentions changing only class names. Since Spring injections usually work on properties you will have a problem identifying the right setters.

Comment: I tried to use file filter, it didn't work. Seems it really doesn't process xml files.
Good point regarding the method names, thanks for the note.